# using Image Tick jQuery for Multiple RadioButtonList

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i'm using this really cool library for modifying the traditional RadioButtonLists.
[Image Tick V 2.0](http://boedesign.com/blog/2008/06/08/imagetick-for-jquery/)
 But how do i use this for playing with Multiple RadioButtonList, like below

```
O option1 (Checked)
O option2
O option3
O option4

O option1 (checked)
O option2
O option3
O option4
```

tried with different "Name" and "id" attributes. So far was able to render two lists, but after clicking on them (here Option3 on first list), the Lists started to act as one list like below

```
O option1 
O option2
O option3 (checked)
O option4

O option1 
O option2
O option3
O option4
```

Its like the script starts to treat both the lists as a single list. Any direction to proceed forward with this?
**Updated My Fiddle link**
http://jsfiddle.net/skriyas/mctcs/236/

Comment: How are you formatting the html?

Comment: i use Razor to render the controls... So i use the @Html.RadioButtonFor(..) to render the list

Comment: Have you tried giving group1 samename, group2 samename, group3 samename?

Comment: yes. That is where i used the Name attribute to differentiate between the lists

Comment: Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wt3GM/  Is that the functionality you are looking for?  Sorry I'm a little confused

Comment: yes,the same one, but with the Image Tick JQuery that i have mentioned above.

Comment: It should work as long as in the "<input type='radio'> tag you have group1 with same name and group2 with same name like in the fiddle.  Can you post the html that is generated by viewing source on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the image tick examples.  Just make sure each you are grouping the radio input buttons by their name.  Then in the script you should have code like this.

```
$("input:radio").imageTick({ // target all the radio buttons instead of selecting by name
    tick_image_path: "images/radio.gif",  // the image you want to use as a selected state of the radio/checkbox
    no_tick_image_path: "images/no_radio.gif", // image you want to use as a non selected state
    image_tick_class: "radios" // the class you want to apply to all images that are dynamically created
});
```

In their example they were selecting the radio element by name so if you copied that code you would have to copy/paste the code multiple times for each group

EDIT:

In your script you are not checking if they are in the same group or not.  I've updated the fiddle here with the check and it works as it should now.  There's probably a better way using filter but I'm not too good with it yet.
http://jsfiddle.net/mctcs/237/

```
$("#tick_img_"+id).click(function(){
            var thisGroup=$(this).next('input').attr('name');   // This is the clicked group         
                $("." + opt.image_tick_class).each(function() { 
                    if($(this).next('input').attr('name') === thisGroup){ // check to only modify clicked gruop
                    //console.log($(this).attr('name'));
                    var r = this.id.split("_");
                    var radio_id = r.splice(2,r.length-2).join("_");
                    $(this).attr('src', no_tick_image_path(radio_id));
                    }
                });
                $("#" + id).trigger("click");

                $(this).attr('src', tick_image_path);

 });
```

Comment: i've added the link in the question above

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fiddle that is working.  You were looping through all the radio buttons and turning them off if they weren't the one that was clicked.  You just forgot to check/filter out only the ones in the group that was clicked

Comment: I had the same solution in my mind. but was not aware of where and how to implement. Thanks for that solution @wirey...